# Sloan digital sky survey galaxies

Tags: galaxy, data-analysis, deep-sky-observing, sky-survey

I am trying to get some data from the [Sloan digital sky survey](http://www.sdss3.org/dr10/data_access/) (SDSS). This task turned out to be challenging for me as someone with only little knowledge about astronomy and maybe someone here can help me. What I need is data for all galaxies of the SDSS with their optical spectroscopy and position.

I suppose I need:

- redshifts
- RA (right ascension)
- dec (declination)
- classifications of all SDSS spectra

from the [Optical Spectra Catalog Data](http://www.sdss3.org/dr10/data_access/bulk.php)

I found a script to convert ra/dec/redshift to x/y/z coordinates.
Will I need "the associated photometric position based matches" and "stellar parameter (SSPP) results" to get RA and dec? I have no idea what these are.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate to ask the SDSS collaboration itself:  helpdesk@sdss3.org

Comment: Also, the coordinates for galaxies are likely to be in Galactic lat/long, which can be converted to x/y/z given redshift. And even I don't know what the two terms you mentioned are (in spite of having a fair knowledge in astronomy), so, as Joshua mentioned, you would probably be better asking SDSS people this stuff.

Comment: "the associated photometric position based matches" = this is a plate image of the sky where the spectrum was taken so you can make sure it's the spectrum of the object you want. "stellar parameter (SSPP) results" = SEGUE Stellar Parameter Pipeline which is an analysis pipeline for stars. I would say no for both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Optical Spectra Query Form](http://skyserver.sdss3.org/dr10/en/tools/search/SQS.aspx). You'll want to set PRIMTARGET to "GALAXY". Here's the list of possible parameters it can return http://skyserver.sdss3.org/dr10/en/help/docs/QS_UserGuide.aspx#Spectroscopy. Note, there is a query limit of 500,000 rows, so you'll have to break up the query since you'll have more spectra than that.